# Call certificate on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, ssl

I am using WebService from a website which is  . 
The thing is that the person in charge of that company send me certificate (.pfx file) and I installed it on my PC.

I created an instance of a class:

```
realServiceReference.Service1SoapClient s = new realServiceReference.Service1SoapClient();
XElement response2 = s.GetLoginWS("USERNAME", CalculateMD5Hash("PASSWORD"), "TOKEN");
Label2.Text = response2.ToString();


Label1.Text = CalculateMD5Hash("PASSWORD").ToString();
```

It return -1 -1 .

But when I try a test link he sent me which is http://test.example.com/ex.asmx. I call an instance of a class with the similar code:

```
testServiceReference.Service1SoapClient s = new testServiceReference.Service1SoapClient();
XElement response2 = s.GetLoginWS("USERNAME", CalculateMD5Hash("PASSWORD"), "TOKEN");
Label2.Text = response2.ToString();


Label1.Text = CalculateMD5Hash("PASSWORD").ToString();
```

It returns login details. I contacted the person in charge and he said "You should call certificate on browser". I searched the web but no luck.

Comment: They should provide docs explaining how to invoke the service. While the question is okay, I'm flagging it as Off Topic because it's impossible to repro.

Comment: @Alex  Nope they haven't. They just gave us the .asmx link, login credentials and nothing else. When I asked for this issue the person in charge told me "You should call certificate on browser", nothing else.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after calling the service and look to see what `response2` is set to. `.ToString()` may not be the best thing.